# Free download manager for Windows 8

Tags: gratis, windows-8, download-manager

I need a free download manager software (for Windows 8) with one condition: It should be able to take over downloads automatically when I click on a download link.

I have tested "Free Download Manager" but no use. It is not taking downloads when I click on a link.

Answer (score 2):

Which browser are you using?

Free Download Manager can do what you want by it may require installing a browser extension / plugin.

If you are using Chrome you can download the plugin from:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/free-download-manager-chr/ahmpjcflkgiildlgicmcieglgoilbfdp

I personally use Chrono. It's a download manager that is only Chrome extension (no software installation needed):
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn

Comment: I am using Chrome. Does "Chrono" has the ability to resume downloads after a system restart ?

Comment: @Vinod KC no. Not posible. It wont even resume. Try if u want to

Comment: @Switch what's the advantage of DAM over FDM? Does DAM work without a browser extension?

Comment: @traveh i dunno. Thought we were talking about Chrono

Comment: @Switch I was talking about FDM in the first part of my answer. I'm using it too sometimes and was wondering if I should switch to DAM since you think so highly of it, but I looked it up and didn't find any advantage. I was wondering if you tried FDM and preferred DAM over FDM.

Answer (score 2):

You seriously must use [*Download Accelerator Manager (DAM)*](http://www.damdownloader.com/).

It is so amazingly powerful that even if you uninstall this manager with a download partially done, and you reinstall it, that partially done download actually resumes!!!!!

If you do not believe me, try it out for yourself. I am telling you my own experience. The actual intention of this is to download data as fast as possible.

I do not know if you can automatically assign downloads to it, you have to copy-past the link. But that sacrifice is nothing in front of the performance you get!

Happy downloading =)

Comment: Thanks Switch. Let me try it. But automatic start is a must.