# Powerful open-source download manager for Android

Tags: android, open-source, download-manager, internet

I often have issues with downloading heavy content on my smart-phone, either because of poor internet connection, or server problems. The download-manager that comes with Android is very weak.

Can anyone recommend a powerful, reliable, stable and open-source download manager for Android.

Preferably downloads must automatically be assigned to the download-manager.

Comment: While waiting for good recommendations, you might wish to check my [Download Manager](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_downloadmanager) list. Not sure about the open-source part, but some of them match at least the other criteria given.

Comment: @Izzy do you know Download Accelerator Manager. i use it on windows. im using it right know to download a movie called Batman vs Dracula. just thought u might want to use it. ill give u a link to an answer posted by me

Comment: @Izzy http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/19354/13550

Comment: I don't use Windows, and I don't use Download Managers on Android – so no, sorry. Otherwise I might have posted an answer instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

There is [GigaGet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=us.shandian.giga), but when downloading a file from Chrome it doesn't appear as a choice of app, or at least not as often as some proprietary managers I've tried. You can share links to it though. It also hasn't been updated in a while, but there is some activity on its GitHub.

Also, there's an Android version of the open source download manager [uGet](http://ugetdm.com/) but the source code specifically for the Android version hasn't been released yet (and it's not on Google Play yet either if that bothers you). I haven't tried it myself either.